# don't insert curly braces in latex-math-mode

Tags: latex, auctex

In `latex-math-mode`, when using any macro, curly braces are inserted. for example using `-g inserts `\gamma{}`. I would like it to produce only `\gamma`. I couln't find a way to do this.

Comment: You are probably inserting `\gamma` outside of a math environment.

Comment: related question that I asked a while ago: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60177/auctex-latex-math-mode-outside-a-mathematical-environment?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not inside a math environment. When the cursor is inside any math mode environment the macro works as expected, with no braces added.

Comment: (1) Don't refer to comments - comments can be deleted at any time. Incorporate whatever you need from comments into your answer. (2) Please develop your answer, to make clearer what the answer is (how it answers the question). Thx.